# Rails: mounting engine inside nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-engines

I am trying to mount an engine at two different points in the same app.

The first point, which is working, is at the root level 'localhost:3000/news'.

The second is one resource deep, with the desired url structure something like this: 'localhost:3000/venues/1/news'. This is not working.

I am initialising the engine in the host app routes file like this

```
  mount NewsEngine::Engine => "/" 
  resources :venues do
    mount NewsEngine::Engine => "/" 
  end
```

Running rake routes however only yields the first level of routes.

```
newsitems GET  /news(.:format)              news_engine/newsitems#index                                       
 newsitem GET  /news/:newsitem_id(.:format) news_engine/newsitems#show
```

Weirdly, referencing even the first level raises an error:

```
=link_to "News", intertain_news_engine.newsitems_path
=> No route matches {:action=>"index"} missing required keys: [:venue_id]
```

I would have expect this error trying to call `venue_newsitems_path` but not `newsitems_path`

The routes file in the engine itself looks like this.

```
NewsEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :newsitems, param: :newsitem_id,
                        only: [:index, :show],
                        path: 'news'

end
```

Venues are retrieved using config blocks in the host application that tell the engine to call a before_action method from the host app application controller - though I can't see how this would be a problem as it currently seems solely down to the routing.